# リストから組み合わせで取り出す際に、要素範囲を指定して列挙したい

Tags: python

pythonにて
`S=0,1,2,....,a(b+1)`までの組み合わせで、この`S`から2つ取り出して列挙していく(`a=4`, `b=2`)やり方でこのようにプログラミングが書けると教えていただいたんですが↓↓↓

```
import itertools
a = 4
b = 2
c = a*(b+1)+1
l = list(itertools.combinations(range(0, c, 1), 2))
print(l)
```

この際に、`S`の`(0,p,p+a*q)`を除いて列挙したいです。
やり方を教えていただきたいです。

(今回は、`p=1`, `q=1`で数値を入れたいです→つまり`(0,1,5)`を取り除きたいです)

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`S` から要素を除いた上で `combinations` を計算したいので、これをそのままコードとして書けばよいです。

たとえば [`list.remove`](https://docs.python.jp/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) を使って下のように書けます。

```
$ python3
>>> import itertools
>>> a = 4
>>> b = 2
>>> p = 1
>>> q = 1
>>> s = list(range(1, a * (b + 1) + 1))
>>> s.remove(p)
>>> s.remove(p + a * q)
>>> s
[2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
>>> list(itertools.combinations(s, 2))
[(2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 6), (2, 7), (2, 8), (2, 9), (2, 10), (2, 11), (2, 12), (3, 4), (3, 6), (3, 7), (3, 8), (3, 9), (3, 10), (3, 11), (3, 12), (4, 6), (4, 7), (4, 8), (4, 9), (4, 10), (4, 11), (4, 12), (6, 7), (6, 8), (6, 9), (6, 10), (6, 11), (6, 12), (7, 8), (7, 9), (7, 10), (7, 11), (7, 12), (8, 9), (8, 10), (8, 11), (8, 12), (9, 10), (9, 11), (9, 12), (10, 11), (10, 12), (11, 12)]
```

除きたい要素が増えたときのために、`for` を使って `S` を作るのも良いでしょう。

```
>>> s = list(range(0, a * (b + 1) + 1))
>>> elem = [0, p, p + a * q]
>>> for i in elem:
...     s.remove(i)
... 
>>> s
[2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

あるいは[リスト内包表記](https://docs.python.jp/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)を使って次のようにも書けます。

```
s = [i for i in range(0, a * (b + 1) + 1) if i not in [0, p, p + a * q]]
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。今回(0,1,5)を抜いた、[2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]から2つを取り出すとしていますが、2つと指定せず　1~10個　取り出したものをすべて列挙してだすにはどうすればいいのでしょうか。

Comment: 別の問題になったようなので、別質問としてご投稿ください。

Answer (score 0):

例えば`filter`関数を使って

```
S = range(0,c,1)
p = 1
q = 1
T = filter(lambda v: v not in (0,p,p+a*q), S)
l = list(itertools.combinations(T, 2))
print(l)
```

とできます。